# Android AAR package for native library

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, aar, maven-central

I'm looking for a way to package a native library into an AAR package, so it would be possible to use it via dependencies declaration in gradle script.

By native library I mean set of .cpp files or compiled static library and a set of header files. So, I mean that the app itself will call the library from native code, not from Java. In other words, the library needed to compile app's native code. So that it will be possible to easily manage dependencies of native code.

Is it even possible?

So far I could only find a lot of questions/examples of how to make an AAR of JNI native library with .so file and its Java interface, so the lib just a Java lib with native implementation, but this is not what I need.

Comment: I found that here
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs
might be some interesting info, but I still don't see how to package it all to AAR

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java - it's a fairly complex build system. And you can include Realm using a Gradle plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/261

Comment: Try **android-fat-aar** gradle script on [GitHub](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar)

Comment: @AlexCohn how does that help in solving my problem? I had a look at that and it seems unrelated at all.

Comment: Fat-aar does not work for static libs, so this s not an answer to your question. But you can probably apply the same principles to distribute the content you need.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks for pointing that out, but I think I already do something similar, see my answer below.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but I prefer to avoid the experimental plugin, which is not compatible with many add-ons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually hacking the gradle scripts works, but is painful and error-prone.

I've recently found a plugin that magically bundles the headers into the AAR files and extracts them and sets up the build scripts when adding the dependency: https://github.com/howardpang/androidNativeBundle

### On the reusable library:

- Add the export plugin:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.ydq.android.gradle.native-aar.export'
  ```
- Define where the header files are:

  ```
  nativeBundleExport {
      headerDir = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/jni/include"
  }
  ```

### On the module that uses it:

- Add the import plugin:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.ydq.android.gradle.native-aar.import'
  ```
- add `include ${ANDROID_GRADLE_NATIVE_BUNDLE_PLUGIN_MK}` to each module that depends on it in your `Android.mk`:

  ```
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myapp.cpp \
  LOCAL_MODULE := myapp
  LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
  include ${ANDROID_GRADLE_NATIVE_BUNDLE_PLUGIN_MK}
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  ```

Comment: I also wrote my own alternative plugin: https://github.com/paulo-raca/ndkLibraries

Comment: Is there a way to use it with CMake based android build?

Comment: AndroidNativeBundle suports it, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: NdkLibraries probably works when exportng, but doesn''t have lhe import code -- PRs welcome

Comment: I'm thinking about to try AndroidNativeBundle, just wanted to ask you why didn't you like it so that you ended up writing your own plugin? Are there any flaws in it?

Comment: @igagis did you end out trying out the plugin? It seems that it requires devs to use it on both sides (uploading and consuming) which doesn't particularly sound ideal

Comment: @IvanGarza yes, I'm using the plugin now for all my libraries. Yes, it has to be used on both sides.

Answer (score 6):

**= UPDATE 2020-06-20 =**

Nowadays, there is a [nice plugin](https://github.com/howardpang/androidNativeBundle) for that, works pretty well.
Thanks to its author and to @Paulo Costa for pointing to it.

**= OBSOLETE =**

Found the following hacky solution to the problem:

Use Android Experimental Gradle plugin version 0.9.1.
The idea is to put library headers and static libraries into .aar.
The headers are put to `ndkLibs/include` and static libs to `ndkLibs/<arch>` for each architecture. Then, in the app, or another lib which depends on this packed lib we just extract `ndkLibs` directory from AAR to the `build` directory in the project. See the example gradle file below.

The `build.gradle` file for the library with comments:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.library"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        buildToolsVersion = '25.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = '1.0'
        }
        ndk {
            platformVersion = 21
            moduleName = "mylib"
            toolchain = 'clang'
            abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'mips', 'mips64']) //this is default
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
            stl = 'c++_static'
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            cppFlags.add("-frtti")

            //Add include path to be able to find headers from other AAR libraries
            cppFlags.add("-I" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/include")
        }

        //For each ABI add link-time library search path to be able to link against other AAR libraries
        abis {
            create("armeabi") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/armeabi")
            }
            create("armeabi-v7a") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/armeabi-v7a")
            }
            create("arm64-v8a") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/arm64-v8a")
            }
            create("x86") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/x86")
            }
            create("x86_64") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/x86_64")
            }
            create("mips") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/mips")
            }
            create("mips64") {
                ldFlags.add("-L" + projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/build/ndkLibs/mips64")
            }
        }
    }

    //Configure this library source files
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                //This does not affect AAR packaging
                exportedHeaders {
                    srcDir "../../src/"
                }

                //This tells which source files to compile
                source {
                    srcDirs '../../src'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Custom Maven repository URLs to download AAR files from
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/igagis/android/'
    }
}

//Our custom AAR dependencies, those in turn are also packed to AAR using the same approach
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'io.github.igagis:libutki:+'
    compile 'io.github.igagis:libsvgdom:+'
    compile 'org.cairographics:cairo:+'
}


//===================================
//=== Extract NDK files from AARs ===
//This is to automatically extract ndkLibs directory from AAR to build directory before compiling any sources
task extractNDKLibs {
    doLast {
        configurations.compile.each {
            def file = it.absoluteFile
            copy {
                from zipTree(file)
                into "build/"
                include "ndkLibs/**/*"
            }
        }
    }
}
build.dependsOn('extractNDKLibs')
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('compile')) {
        task.dependsOn('extractNDKLibs')
    }
}



//=================================
//=== pack library files to aar ===
//This stuff re-packs the release AAR file adding headers and static libs to there, but removing all shared (.so) libs, as we don't need them. The resulting AAR is put to the project root directory and can be uploaded to Maven along with POM file (you need to write one by hand).

def aarName = name

task copyNdkLibsToAAR(type: Zip) {
    baseName = aarName
    version = "\$(version)"
    extension = 'aar.in'
    destinationDir = file('..') //put resulting AAR file to upper level directory

    from zipTree("build/outputs/aar/" + aarName + "-release.aar")
    exclude('**/*.so') //do not include shared libraries into final AAR
    from("../../src") {
        exclude('makefile')
        exclude('soname.txt')
        exclude('**/*.cpp')
        exclude('**/*.c')
        into('ndkLibs/include')
    }
    from("build/intermediates/binaries/debug/lib"){
        include('**/*.a')
        into('ndkLibs')
    }
}

build.finalizedBy('copyNdkLibsToAAR')
```

Comment: google has dropped experimental gradle plugin, so this approach is kind of dead now. But perhaps something similar can be achieved with standard plugin also.

Comment: Unfortunately this prefab thing seem to have died too for public development. 3 years later and i still have not seen even the most fundamental software like openssl + curl packaged as prefabs and the plugin still missed one of the most important thing:  creating a aar from an already compiled so library.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents), it doesn't look like it is possible. I am pasting below the contents:

**Anatomy of an AAR file**

The file extension for an AAR file is .aar, and the Maven artifact type should be aar as well. The file itself is a zip file containing the following mandatory entries:

- /AndroidManifest.xml
- /classes.jar
- /res/
- /R.txt

Additionally, an AAR file may include one or more of the following optional entries:

- /assets/
- /libs/name.jar
- /jni/abi_name/name.so (where abi_name is one of the Android supported ABIs)
- /proguard.txt
- /lint.jar

As said above, the mandatory entry includes a jar. You can however can give a try by manually deleting the jar file by unzipping the aar and zip back again. I am not sure whether it will work though.

Comment: It is pretty clear that there is no official way of doing it, I got a direct answer from developers here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/261, the intention of the question is to find possible good workarounds

Comment: How exactly do you include the optional entries into the AAR? More specifically, `libs` and `jni`

Answer (score 0):

Although i haven't personally tried to, i found a number of steps [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/261):

Probably indirectly [tried with shared lib once a while ago], and I personally do not think it is worthwhile:

- build your lib first to generate a static lib, and one aar
  [model.library does not tuck *.a into libs directory though]
- unzip your aar, and put *.a into libs folder
- find a place for your headers file
- zip it up back to aar inside your app, make aar to be your dependent lib, so it will be extracted into exploded-aar folder; then the colorful picture appears.
- add the intermediate explodeded aar directory into include path
  I think it is too hacky and may not be a good idea to impose those into your customers.

traditional way of distributing lib and header files directly is still better, comparing to the above hacking.
For building libs, cmake way is much better, checkout hello-libs in master-cmake branch, hope this helps

Comment: yep, that github issue was submitted by me, I'm just looking for better workarounds which would not require user to enter include paths manually