# How to put file inside AAR classes.jar when build with Android Studio

Tags: android, jar, java-native-interface

i want to build a library in android with file inside the classes.jar inside AAR

```
public class JNI {

    static {
        try {
            NativeUtil.loadLibraryFromJar("/jni/lib-jni.so");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static native String getPassword();
}
```

the nativeUtil from [AdamHeinrich](https://www.adamheinrich.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-load-native-jni-library-from-jar/)

how do i put the file inside JAR? thanks

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140809/android-aar-package-for-native-library

Answer (score 0):

You need a gradle script to take care of the extra dependencies. I can recommend [android-fat-aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar) from personal experience.